# If A is nonsingular, do we know that the diagonal elements of L and U are nonzero?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Does a square matrix A being nonsingular imply that for A=LU decomposition the diagonal elements of L and U are all nonzero?

I was just wondering because intuitively, it seems that A being nonsingular implies that A is full rank and dim(LU) can't equal dim(A) unless the diagonal elements are all nonzero... Thanks

Comment: That is correct, in fact usually the diagonal elements of L are all 1.

Comment: Note though that A being nonsingular does not imply that an LU decomposition even exists. Sometimes only a PLU decomposition exists.

Comment: Thank you. I was reading about that. I learned that all the minors have to be nonzero. Am I correct that an LU decomposition is unique only if no pivoting is required?

Comment: It is never unique; you can always rescale to make a new LU decomposition given one. It is unique if you force L to have diagonal 1. It only exists if pivoting is not required.

Comment: note: http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/INF-MAT3350/h07/undervisningsmateriale/chap8slides.pdf this source gives a theorem about uniqueness I found nice for people interested. If a matrix is nonsingular and A=LU exists it is unique

Comment: Yes, but note that they made the assumption I mentioned that L is unit-diagonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (guarded) yes. If $A$ can be factored as $A = LU$, where $L$ is lower and $U$ upper triangular, then $0 \not = \text{det}(A) = \text{det}(L) \text{det}(U)$ implies that $L$ and $U$ are both nonsingular. Since they are triangular, they cannot have zero elements on their main diagonal.